# Retrieving PostgreSQL TEXT type using Spring data JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have a table "comment" with below structure

```
   Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------|-----------------------------|-----------|----------|---------
 id          | uuid                        |           | not null |
 author      | character varying(100)      |           | not null |
 content     | text                        |           | not null |
```

The corresponding entity class code is below:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "author", updatable = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String author;

    @Column(name = "content", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String content;
}
```

When I am retrieving the data using `JpaRepository`, in the content field I am getting some number rather than actual text I had saved.
How can I get the actual value that I stored in the content field?

Comment: It seems the obfuscation layer decided to map `text` to the dreaded "large objects".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Should I just switch to varchar without any length limit..?